# Z3py polish notation output

Tags: z3, z3py

The default output for z3py expression is in infix notation. Is there a option to set the output format to polish notation?

I assume there may be an option similar to `set_option(html_mode=False)` But haven't been able to find any supporting documentation detailing the options I can set.

Currently I am using `.sexpr()` to get the internal representation of the expression. But this has overhead when parsing as it contains extra information I need to filter.

Here is the example I am working with at currently http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/BNn2

`[[N ≤ 4, N ≥ 2]]`

I would like it printed as  `<= N 4, >= N 2`

Is there a option I can set to change the output of print?
Or is the best approach to use the `.sexpr()` representation?

Comment: Could http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775122/z3-convert-z3py-expression-to-smt-lib2-from-solver-object and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628279/z3-convert-z3py-expression-to-smt-lib2 help?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to process the expression, then you can traverse the Z3 expression directly. It will be more efficient and less prone to errors. Here is a post that shows how to do it in C++:

- [Traversing Z3_ast tree in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501540/traversing-z3-ast-tree-in-c-c)

Here is an example using C#

- [Is there a way of querying or accessing the structure of a Z3 expression via the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084659/is-there-a-way-of-querying-or-accessing-the-structure-of-a-z3-expression-via-the/14086023#14086023)

Here is a related post showing how these APIs can be used from Python:

- [Reading a Z3 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927741/reading-a-z3-file/9928715#9928715)