# Display declarations parsed from an SMT-LIB2 file

Tags: java, z3

I'm using Z3 with Java API. In my SMT-LIB2 file, there are several variables:

```
(declare-fun x0 () Int)
(declare-fun x1 () Bool)
; alot more
```

I want to get all these variables, and store them in an array of `Expr`. From the example distributed with z3, I find the API `SMTLIBDecls` that get declarations parsed from an SMT-LIB1 file, but there is no similar API for SMT-LIB2. How can I get the declarations?

Thanks.

Comment: OMG! you are that famous angry boy! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no function for this purpose, but it is easy to get the declarations by traversing the expressions. This has previously been asked for C/C++, but the answer applies to Java as well: [Z3 4.3.1 C-API parse_smtlib2_string: Where to get declarations from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646808/z3-4-3-1-c-api-parse-smtlib2-string-where-to-get-declarations-from)

Additionally, these posts may be of interest as well:
[Traversing Z3_ast tree in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501540/traversing-z3-ast-tree-in-c-c), [How to find out if a z3_ast corresponds to a clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862109/how-to-find-out-if-a-z3-ast-corresponds-to-a-clause/8862929#8862929)

Comment: Thanks. In the answer for "Where to get declarations from", there is a link to an example: http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#examples/tptp/tptp5.cpp, but the link is dead. Could you please check it for me?

Comment: Ah! It looks like these links don't contain information about the branch that the file is in. In this case examples/tptp/tptp5.cpp is in the unstable branch, but not available in the master branch (yet).